# PHP Mail Help Which is getting sent in HTML code

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send an mail to an email account. And in the content part of the email/ message part of the email i want to include an html file.
Below is my code for php file:

```
 <?php

$to = "my_email@email.com";
$from = "something@something.com";
$subject = "This is the subject";


$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Put your HTML here
$message = file_get_contents('index.html');

$headers = "From: $from \r\n". 
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

?>
```

But the problem is, when the mail is sent, it shows the whole HTML code in the email content. i dont want the code to be seen. But proper content. Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Not only your `$headers` are renamed to `$header` in `mail`, but you reset it after `file_get_contents()`

Comment: I changed header to headers.. what else do i do?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

to

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

HTML Message send example :

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Reference : [**(PHP 4, PHP 5) mail — Send mail**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)